# cPanel doesn't update from GitHub remote repo (doesn't fetch changes)

Tags: git, cpanel

I have a **private** repo called "ropoz" (a random name) on GitHub and have cloned it to my server. Everything works fine when I use the terminal (command line):

```
$ git fetch
Enter passphrase for key...
...
```

I can pull, fetch, ... It just asks for the passphrase of the SSH key I have created and it is not a huge problem.

The problem is when I use the cPanel git interface to update the repo from remote: it says  `Information: The “ropoz test” repository is up-to-date.` but it's not! It cannot detect changes on the repo and I don't know why.

[image]

Comment: maybe you are on a different branch? like `main` instead of `master`?

Comment: Yeah it was a mistake! However, I did `checkout main` but still doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using an SSH key without passphrase, just for cPanel.
That is, after all, what the [cPanel documentation](https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/guide-to-git-set-up-access-to-private-repositories/) recommends.

If not, check if [adding your key to an ssh-agent](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent) would be enough to not have to enter your passphrase, both from CLI or cPanel.
However, [this 2021 article](https://suleinsights.medium.com/how-to-configure-cpanel-git-version-control-with-ssh-key-authentication-ffe74a590680)  from  [Abdulhaqq Sule](https://twitter.com/suleinsights) confirms:

> cPanel Git™ Version Control is not compatible with keys that use a passphrase.